# Encode and decode string before saving to database using C#

Tags: c#, localization, decode, encode

I am accepting some keywords from user. These keywords I want to save in my db.

These keywords can be in a number of languages.(English, French, Chinese and so on)

Once saved in db in some encoded format later I also need to read it back later after decoding it.

I have tried this and does not work as I later put these values as attribute in an xml file.

```
public static string EncodeKeyword(string keyword)
{
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(keyword));
}

public static string DecodeKeyword(string encodedKeyword)
{
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encodedKeyword));
}
```

After using this conversion my xml generated is

```
<header>
    <row keyword_term="'Y?e,g"></row>
    <row keyword_term="'Y?e,g^W"></row>
    <row keyword_term="'Y?e"></row>
</header>
```

and this fails...

[image]

Please advice.

**EDIT**: I cannot change the db column type :(

Comment: Why encode? Store in the db as NVarchar (Unicode)

Comment: if your on SQL @Alex best option. try to keep unicode for multilanguage support.

Comment: @AlexK.I cannot change the db type, any other way you suggest. Thanks

Comment: you cannot because it fails or because of requirements by someone else ?

Comment: What database is it and what datatype is the column your using?

Comment: its because of requirement.

Comment: ms sql, i am actually passing the above xml to an stored procedure which accepts an `,@keyword_list XML `

Comment: If you need to support unicode (Chinese) and so on and your db column isn't Unicode and you can not change it to nvarchar, you'll need to transform your unicode chars to something which is ascii, like Base64. But than you loose the ability to easily search within the column in your database.

Comment: in SQL insert query you can enforce unicode like this `INSERT INTO Comments (Detail) VALUES (N'the N before this string enforce unicode save')`